# How to convert sql server table data into MS Access(.mdb) file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have SQL Database table with 6664055 rows, I want to convert this SQL Server table data to MS Access format(.MDB), How Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

[SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)